# reengineer FOR loop in r

Tags: r, for-loop

I have 15 million rows of a data.frame that need to be scanned for records within the start and end date in another smaller data.frame. 
Basically if the id matches, incurred date is within start and end date of small dataframe records then it needs to be flagged with a sequential number. 
So far I have been able to successfully achieve it using for loop. 
But as u might have guessed extremely inefficient takes upto 24 hours. 
I am hoping someone could help me with this. 
df_in is reference dataframe.

```
for ( i in 1:dim(df_in)[1]){
df1[which(df1$id %in% df_in[i,"id"] & 
df1$Incurred_dt>=df_in[i,"start date”]
& df1$Incurred_dt<=df_in[i," end date"])
,"seq"]<-i
print(i)}
```

df_in

```
id  start date  end date
1   1/1/2016    10/1/2016
2   2/1/2016    11/1/2016
3   4/1/2016    12/1/2016
```

resulting df1

```
id  incurred date   seq
1   3/1/2016        1
1   9/2/2016        1
1   6/3/2016        1
1   9/4/2016        1
1   10/5/2016   
1   10/6/2016   
1   10/7/2016   
1   10/8/2016   
2   9/2/2016        2
2   6/3/2016        2
2   9/4/2016        2
2   10/5/2016       2
2   10/6/2016       2
2   10/7/2016       2
2   9/2/2016        2
3   6/3/2016        3
3   9/4/2016        3
3   10/5/2016       3
3   10/6/2016       3
3   10/7/2016       3
3   10/7/2016       3
```

Comment: Could you include a sample df1 so that your loop may be run reproducibly?

Comment: at a glance you should look into `foverlaps` from `data.table`. 15 million rows isn't that many.

Comment: Raw df1 is basically one above with just id and incurred date column...